# Splash-screen doesn't show it contents

Tags: pygtk, splash-screen

I'm having some trouble showing a splashscreen during some heavy work in my application in Python-gtk. I've been searching on Google and found this link: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577919-splash-screen-gtk/. Since the example is quite clear, I downloaded the program and ran it on my computer. However, the splashscreen didn't show its contents.
Could it be that some configuration parameter of Gtk is set wrong? How come adding the code:

```
while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration()
```

right after showing the splashscreen doesn't work in my case?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried adding:

```
        while gtk.events_pending():
            gtk.main_iteration()
```

right after the `self.window.show_all()` in `splashScreen`, and that worked. Before that, it didn't display the text, "This shouldn't take too long... :)".

This works because it ensures that the splash screen is rendered immediately, rather than leaving it to chance, which I guess must randomly work for some people (the guy who wrote this code and the other guy who replied here) and not for others (you and me).

Comment: That doesn't work for me neither. Indeed, there is already a "while gtk.events_pending ..." just after the initialization of splashscreen (in the main function). I'm working on Gnome but tried it on the xfce desktop and there it works...

Comment: I'm not talking about the one in the main function (as that one doesn't seem to do anything on my computer), I'm talking about adding one right after `self.window.show_all()` in `splashScreen`. Did you do that? And it still doesn't work? If so... strange.

Comment: Sorry, I must have done it wrong. Now it works :-). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but I had the same issue with Gtk+3, and using Gtk.events_pending() had no effect, so I took a different route.

Basically, I just put a button to manually clear the splash screen, which I've seen plenty of commercial apps do. Then I call window.present() on the splash screen after creating the main window to keep the splash screen in front. This seems to be just the pause Gtk+3 needs to actually show the splash screen content *before* showing the main window opening behind it.

```
class splashScreen():

    def __init__(self):

        #I happen to be using Glade
        self.gladefile = "VideoDatabase.glade"
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)
        self.window = self.builder.get_object("splashscreen")

        #I give my splashscreen an "OK" button
        #This is not an uncommon UI approach
        self.button = self.builder.get_object("button")

        #Button cannot be clicked at first
        self.button.set_sensitive(False)

        #Clicking the button will destroy the window
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.clear)
        self.window.show_all()

        #Also tried putting this here to no avail
        while Gtk.events_pending():
            Gtk.main_iteration()

    def clear(self, widget):
        self.window.destroy()

class mainWindow():

    def __init__(self, splash):
        self.splash = splash

        #Tons of slow initialization steps
        #That take several seconds

        #Finally, make the splashscreen OK button clickable
        #You could probably call splash.window.destroy() here too
        self.splash.button.set_sensitive(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":  

    splScr = splashScreen()

    #Leaving this here, has no noticeable effect
    while Gtk.events_pending():
        Gtk.main_iteration()

    #I pass the splashscreen as an argument to my main window
    main = mainWindow(splScr)

    #And make the splashscreen present to make sure it is in front
    #otherwise it gets hidden
    splScr.window.present()

    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code in the link you gave and it does display the splashscreen's components. But it may have appeared to not display them for you perhaps because the splashscreen window isn't given a size? I added:

`self.window.set_size_request(300,300)`

to the sample code and sure enough the label does appear.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Unfortunately, that doesn't help. It shows a window with nothing written in it..

Comment: What about the 'main window', the one that displays after the splashscreen? Does that one show its contents?

Answer (score 0):

While Chris Harrington's answer works, it uses a number of deprecated API's and requires a manual button press to close the dialog, so I wanted to contribute an alternate solution that uses neither:

```
import time
import gi
import threading

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib


class SplashScreen(Gtk.Dialog):
    __gtype_name__ = "SplashScreen"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="Loading - Example App", modal=True)
        self.set_decorated(False)

        self.set_default_size(512, 522)  # add 10 pixels vertically for label

        label = Gtk.Label(label="Loading...")
        img = Gtk.Image.new_from_file("splash_screen_image_512x512.jpg")

        box = self.get_content_area()
        box.add(img)
        box.add(label)


class MainWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    __gtype_name__ = "MainWindow"

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.ApplicationWindow.__init__(self, title='Example App')

        label = Gtk.Label(label="All done!")
        self.add(label)
        self.set_default_size(200, 100)

        self.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER_ALWAYS)


def do_work(win, mainWin):
    time.sleep(5) # 5 sec sleep to simulate blocking operation
    win.destroy()
    mainWin.show_all()


win = SplashScreen()
win.show_all()
mainWin = MainWindow()
# use thread to allow blocking I/O ops without preventing execution of Gtk.main() below
worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: do_work(win, mainWin))
worker_thread.start()
Gtk.main()
```